# How to override default behavior of htpasswd for a subdirectory?

Tags: apache-2.2

I've included the following in http.conf to password protect the root directory and all subdirectories:

```
<Directory /root>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
    Require user dummy
</Directory>
```

However I would like to allow all access to a subdirectory, `subdirectory` but the following code I've included in http.conf isn't working

```
<Directory /root/subdirectory>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

How would I prevent the default behavior of htpasswd from working on that subdirectory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Satisfy Any`:

```
<Directory /root/subdirectory>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```